# can use more than 1 column in MySQL Group BY?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I want to write these SQL Query:

```
CREATE VIEW `uniaverage` AS 
  SELECT `averagegrade`.`mjr`,`averagegrade`.`lev`, 
     AVG(`averagegrade`.`average`) AS `uniAVG` 
  FROM `averagegrade` GROUP BY `averagegrade`.`lev`, `averagegrade`.`mjr`;
```

But MySQL Query Browser gives me this error:

```
Operand Should Contain 1 column(s)
```

I somewhere read that I can use group by on more than 1 column!!!
How can I solve this error? or how can I change the Query to get the same result?

Comment: Are you sure the error refers to the `GROUP BY` clause? The syntax you give is appropriate, and IWFM.

Comment: I 99% sure because I have no operan in my Query except group by that have 2 argument

Comment: that, believe it or not, is not enough, in part because there are other operands (to AVG, for example). Are there any differences, no matter how trivial seeming, between the query you posted and what you ran? What version of MySQL are you using? What is the type of table averagegrade? Actually, what is the definition of table average grade (use `SHOW CREATE TABLE averagegrade`? What is the result of `EXPLAIN` on the `SELECT` statement (remove the `CREATE VIEW` clause)? Try running the query from the command line client to see if it tells you where in the statement the problem lies.

Comment: Your code here is fine. Your error must have been caused by code you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple comma-separated columns or expressions in a GROUP BY clause exactly like the OP did. To take an example from [the MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html):

```
SELECT id, FLOOR(value/100) AS val
FROM tbl_name
GROUP BY id, val;
```

***Don't*** use `CONCAT()` instead as [the accepted answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2750451/1709587); it will give you incorrect results, since `CONCAT('foo', 'bar', 'baz')` and `CONCAT('fo', 'obarb', 'az')` are the same.

The SQL posted by the OP is fine as it is. The error message he was receiving must have been caused by something else in his query that he removed before posting here; his posted code does not generate the error he says it does. Here's proof:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE averagegrade (mjr int, lev int, average int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO averagegrade VALUES (5,6,7), (5,6,7), (100, 200, 300);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> 
mysql> -- OP's SQL, copied verbatim:
mysql> CREATE VIEW `uniaverage` AS 
    ->   SELECT `averagegrade`.`mjr`,`averagegrade`.`lev`, 
    ->      AVG(`averagegrade`.`average`) AS `uniAVG` 
    ->   FROM `averagegrade` GROUP BY `averagegrade`.`lev`, `averagegrade`.`mjr`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql>   
mysql> SELECT * FROM uniaverage;
+------+------+----------+
| mjr  | lev  | uniAVG   |
+------+------+----------+
|    5 |    6 |   7.0000 |
|  100 |  200 | 300.0000 |
+------+------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: TBH my question was for 5 years ago and I dont remember what was the actual problem but @Ian's answer solved my problem yet your solution seems legit too

Comment: This is how to write a GREAT answer. Everyone else take note. You can actually just run this answer query by query and verify every step of the way. If OP had posted the question in the same manner, he would have never posted it, or posted it the right way, or, most likely, he would have found the issue himself. Be thorough like Mark did here!

Comment: In case anyone ends up here, I got the OP's error "operand should contain 1 column(s)" because I just absent mindedly put my group by columns in parenthesis. The OP didn't say they did that, but the fact that they got the error makes me think when they typed in the query here they didn't include the parenthesis. Just a simple mistake! And here I am on stack overflow looking for the same error. 

so TLDR;
group by (col1, col2, col3) = original error,  
group by col1, col2, col3 = works like a champ.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
GROUP BY CONCAT(field1, field2, field3, etc)
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: No! The OP's original GROUP BY clause was correct; multiple comma-separated columns in GROUP BY are supported, are part of the ANSI SQL standard, and have been supported by MySQL as far back in history as I can easily check ([5.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html), released in 2005). Doing `CONCAT` instead is not only unnecessary and inefficient, but *incorrect*; it means that `('foo', 'bar', 'baz')` and `('fo', 'obarb', 'az')` will be incorrectly grouped together.

Comment: This is actually what DID NOT work for me and the reason why I am here. The solution is to remove commas around the fields list!